# What are the advantages of using BEM or ABEM notation over combined classes?

Tags: html, css

I agree BEM/ABEM brings a naming convention to classes we use in our markup. But what are the advantages over combined classes?

For example, let's take the following code. What would be the advantages of using BEM notation?

### Combined classes

```html
<button class="btn primary">Submit</button>
```

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.btn.primary {
  background: blue;
}
```

### BEM

```html
<button class="btn btn--primary">Submit</button>
```

```css
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.btn--primary {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: It's a convention defined by rules. Having rules means you can test for those. When a class breaks a rule, the developer can be notified.  for example if you forget the  the `.btn` part of `.btn.primary`. the developer has to notice this himself. For BEM, a linter can flag that the class is not adhering to bem and signify something might be amiss. there is no technical advantage. it's more of a human advantage.

Answer (score 1):

combined classes like primary can be use as universally not only in buttons so something that we define to use it with whatever html element when we need, the btn-primary or btn--primary is also just a class but we know we are not 100% can use it universally with whatever the html element, but we are sure it is for button element.

- It also helps to sort our code for javascript code like when we can select only primary buttons or some specific class name.